# Finding Items in Struct and edit them

Tags: c, pointers, struct, filtering, arrow-functions

i have a problem in my code (Case 2), I try to get the position of the item what I get from the scanf() but when I try to get the position it give me a complete random number like 537890.
I can't figure out why my code do that, because the max size of my struct ist 200.

I'm not sure if its because I tried to do `&find==wh[a]->artikel`

```
int main() {

    struct managementtool {
        char artikel[200];
        int anzahl;
    };

    //wh = warehouse

        struct managementtool **wh = malloc(200 * sizeof(struct managementtool *));

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            wh[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct managementtool));
        }


    printf("Welcome to Warehouse Management 97\n\n\nWhat do you want to do ?\n");


    int x,v,f,i,exit,all,end,a,b;


    char ques,find, nu1;

    do {
        i=0;
        printf("\n(1)Add article\n(2)Edit article.\n(3)Search entry.\n(4)Show stock.\n(5)Exit\n");
        scanf("%x",&x);

        switch (x) {
            case 1://add
                do {

                    printf("\nEnter the product name:  ");
                    scanf("%s", wh[f]->artikel);

                    printf("\nAmount of products:  ");
                    scanf("%i", &wh[f]->anzahl);

                    printf("\n\nAdd another product ? (Y/N)");
                    // add a space before % to skip leading whitespace
                    scanf(" %c", &ques);
                    f++;
                    switch (ques) {
                        case 'Y':
                            v++;
                            break;
                        case 'N':
                            end = 1;
                            v = 0;
                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("Wrong entry\n");
                            break;
                    }
                } while (end != 1);
                if (v >= 2) {
                    printf("Product added successfully\n\n");
                }else {
                    printf("Products have been successfully added\n\n");
                }
                break;

            case 2://edit
                printf("Which article do you want to edit?");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s", &find);
                for (a=0;a<f;a++) {
                    if (&find==wh[a]->artikel) {
                        b=a;
                    }
                }
                if (b==0) {
                    printf("Article not found");
                }
                printf("f: %i, b:%i",f,b);
                puts(wh[b]->artikel);
                printf("Amount: %d\n", wh[b]->anzahl);

                break;
            case 3://search
                break;
            case 4://Spam-it

                while (i<f) {
                    printf("\nProduct number %i\n", i+1);
                    printf("Name: ");
                    puts(wh[i]->artikel);
                    printf("Amount: %d\n", wh[i]->anzahl);
                    i++;
                }
                printf("\nTotal amount of Items: %i", all);
                break;
            case 5://go away
                printf("Goodbye :)");
                exit=1;
                break;
            default://well
                printf("Wrong Input\n");
                break;
        }
        all=0;
        while (i<f) {

            all += wh[i]->anzahl;
            i++;
        }
    } while (exit==0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &find);`. Please read the scanf manual to see what `%s` means. It requires a character array  and you have given it a pointer to a single character.

Comment: Also, always check the return value of functions. In particular, it is important to check the results of `scanf` before proceeding to use the parsed results.

Comment: Note that passing an input-only stream to `fflush` (as in e.g. `fflush(stdin)`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*. Some compilers add it as a non-portable and very non-standard extension, please don't use it.

Comment: And why do you use `scanf("%x",&x);`? It seems you're not really sure about how to use `scanf`. Perhaps you should take a few steps back, and refresh your class-notes or your tutorials or your text-books?

Comment: As for `&find==wh[a]->artikel` itself, I assume you want to compare two strings to see if they are equal. Well that's not what the expression is doing, it will be comparing two *pointers*, and they will never be equal. Again, please take a few steps back, refresh class-notes, tutorials and text-books.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm in the freshman year where I need this to pass the class, for sure I'm not the best but I try my best, I appreciate your help and read some scanf tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

In C you need to use strcmp instead of using == to compare strings. You should also use fgets instead of scanf it will make your life easier, you don't have to worry about trying to flush. Example : fgets( my_string_buffer, number_of_char_maximum_to_read , stdin ) . Example for strcmp : if(! strcmp( string1 , string2) , strcmp returns 0 if they are identical.